# How do set certain act up authorization for users/admin in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, activeadmin

I currently have a user model that has users/and an enumerator for admin. I'm trying to set a couple things up, so any help is appreciated. 
1. How do I set it up where only admins and current users can view and edit their information.
2. How do I set it up where only admins can create new users.
Basically what steps do I need to users can only access their information, and protect the accounts. I've attached my active admin/user.rb and some basic authorization for posts I already have.

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :name, :admin, :avatar, :bio, :location
  scope_to :current_user
  actions :all, :except => [:destroy, :new], unless: proc {current_user.admin?}



  index do
    column :name
    column :email
    column :admin
    column :location
    image_column :avatar, style: :thumb
    actions
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :name
      f.input :email
      f.input :bio
      f.input :location
      f.input :admin, label: "Admin"
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
      f.input :avatar
    end
      f.actions
  end

  filter :name


end
```

I already have some basic authorization with Pundit as well.

```
class PostPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :post

  def initialize(user, post)
    @post = post
    @user = user
  end

  def index?
    true
  end

  def show?
    true
  end

  def create?
    user.admin? || @post.user == user
  end

  def create?
    user.admin? || @post.user == user
  end

  def destroy?
    user.admin? || @post.user == user
  end

end
```

Comment: Have you configured Pundit adapter for authorization with ActiveAdmin ?

Comment: Not yet, I'll need to look into that.

Comment: You'll have to do this first - `config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::PunditAdapter` in `active_admin.rb`

Comment: This [reference](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/13-authorization-adapter.md#using-the-pundit-adapter) should help.